# Integrating Minio with a .NET Project using an Identity Provider

Tags: .net, authentication, authorization, identityserver4, minio

I am working on a .NET project where I need to integrate Minio as an object storage solution while using IdentityServer4 as the Identity Provider for authentication and authorization. I've been trying to set up this integration, but I'm facing some challenges.

Specifically, I would like to know:

- What are the steps involved in integrating Minio with a .NET project?
- How can I configure Minio to work seamlessly with IdentityServer4 for authentication and authorization?
- Are there any code examples or resources that demonstrate this integration?
- Additionally, I'm curious about the protocol that is most commonly suggested for achieving this integration. What protocol do you recommend using for communication between Minio and the .NET application when IdentityServer4 is the Identity Provider?

Any guidance, code examples, or resources related to this integration would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

I am trying to achieve this with minio's OpenId Connect but have not reached any final results so far.

Comment: There are a **lot** of questions here, some of which are candidates for closure. To prevent the question from being closed, please ask a specific, single question i.e. 'how do I secure MinIO buckets using Identity Provider?' (if that question does not exist already).